# How can create custom cart price rule for Custom Module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, adminform

I have a need for cart price rules in my custom module..anyone knows that how to add code in **Form.php**?

Look Like That.

[image]

Comment: [This article](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/) can help you

Comment: in article mixed code. I need core code. like as just add in form.php lik as

Comment: $renderer = $this->rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $this->getUrl('vendor_rules/example_rule/newConditionHtml/form/rule_conditions_fieldset')
        );
  
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );

Comment: but its not working..

Comment: See this tutorial, I hope it will save your time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMw3W6XwUl4&index=37&list=PL98CDCbI3TNvPczWSOnpaMoyxVISLVzYQ

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143029)